# why does scanf takes space more than I give?

Tags: c, scanf

why does scanf takes extra size than I gave it? like there is something wrong:

```
int main() {
    printf("enter the first distance:\n");
    printf("Feet: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &d1.feet);
    printf("Inch:");
    scanf("%d\n", &d2.inch);

    printf("enter the second distance:\n");
    printf("Feet: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &d2.feet);
    printf("inch: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &d2.inch);

    sum.feet = d1.feet + d2.feet;
    sum.inch = d1.inch + d2.inch;

    printf("sum of distance: %d, %d", sum.feet, sum.inch);
    return 0;
}
```

[that what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iis52.jpg)

Comment: 1. Where are the declarations for `d1.feet` etc. 2. What is your evidence

Comment: `d1.inch` is never set.

Comment: @EdHeal I didn't include it in the post

Comment: I know that - why not add the evidence

Comment: @user3121023 thanks it works

Comment: As implied above there is a typo: the first `scanf("%d\n", &d2.inch);` should be `scanf("%d\n", &d1.inch);`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should always check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Secondly, if you read the previously linked reference you will see that the `"%d"` format *skips* leading white-space.

Thirdly, by having a trailing white-space in the `scanf` format, you are telling `scanf` to skip *trailing* white-space. While it does that, it needs something to read which is *not* a white-space, or it will not know when the spaces end.

I *guess* the third problem is what you really ask about.